# What is the meaning of 不器用で (Bukiyōde) when describing a person?

Tags: meaning, usage

I found that it means "awkward, clumsy". I was wondering if it may has other meanings?
I would also appreciate giving examples on how the word is used. (The more, the better.)
Thank you

edit: Can it be used to say that a person is hard to deal with?

Comment: You could go to jisho.org or google the term if you are looking for usage/meaning help.

Comment: A [few sentence examples](http://jisho.org/search/%E5%99%A8%E7%94%A8%20%23sentences) with both 器用 and 不器用

Answer (score 1, accepted):

不器用な人 can mean two things depending on the context:

1. a person who is not good at detailed work (cannot properly handle knives or drivers, drops things often, etc)
2. a person who is not good at communicating with others or managing human relationships (especially in romantic contexts) **EDIT**: Basically 不器用な人 is a negative word, but it may refer to an honest and straight person who does not rely on frivolous communication skills.