# Japanese word meaning "clumsy"

Tags: word-requests

What would we call a person who in ungraceful, clumsy in movement?

Is there a Japanese adjective or noun with the meaning?[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the meaning of 不器用で (Bukiyōde) when describing a person?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/56692/what-is-the-meaning-of-%e4%b8%8d%e5%99%a8%e7%94%a8%e3%81%a7-bukiy%c5%8dde-when-describing-a-person)

Comment: Not really. 不器用な人 is not someone who’d often bump into furniture, for example. I’m looking for a word that would mean that.

Comment: What about へたくそ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the word you are looking for is **どじ**
[Here is the jisho definition](https://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%A9%E3%81%98) but it doesn't do the word justice at all. I think it would be better to look up example sentences to get a feel of how it is used.
Here is one to get you started

> ほんとにドジで、しょっちゅうなにかを落としそうになったり、もう少しで大けがをしそうになったりした。

I found this sentence in the NINJAL corpus [どじ](https://nlb.ninjal.ac.jp/headword/AN.00874/)